# How to get the row before and after a specific value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Lets suppose MySQL table is structured as follows:

**(Timestamp | Value)**

```
(4h00  | 3)  ; 
(5h00  | 5)  ; 
(6h00  | 0)  ; 
(7h00  | 0)  ; 
(8h00  | 2)  ; 
(9h00  |10)  ; 
(10h00 | 0)  ; 
(11h00 | 3)  ;
```

I want to get the line where `(Value != 0)` before any appearance of `(Value = 0)` AND the first line where `(Value != 0)` after the appearance of `(Value = 0)`.

Means in this case, the query should return

```
(5h00  |  5) ;
(8h00  |  2) ; 
(9h00  | 10) ; 
(11h00 |  3) ;
```

this is the structure of my table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `latency` (
  `key` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idReport` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  `loss` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idReport`,`timestamp`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`)
)
```

Comment: Don't you have any `PK` in your table?

Comment: i have an auto-incremented key

Comment: So, do you want your data sorted on that auto_increment field in this case?

Comment: it would be better if the data is sorted by timestamp, because later i will have to calculate the duration between every 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` AS tcurrent
INNER JOIN `table` AS tnext
    ON tnext.timestamp = tcurrent.timestamp+60*60
WHERE tnext.value = 0
    AND tcurrent.value != 0
```

You may adapt the `+60*60`: a `DATE_ADD` for `1 HOUR` is easier to read. Also, do not forget to index columns properly (a `UNIQUE INDEX (timestamp, value)` sounds good).

Comment: Actually the timestamps are not periodic. I just picked these values to simplify. and i already have an index for the columns.

Comment: @EatingTooMuch Then you may do the join on a `id` colulmn that gets auto-incremented. It will be easier than nesting queries to pick "the next timestamp row"

Answer (score 0):

You could use row numbering logic , something like this

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT RN FROM
(
SELECT L.*,
         IF (L.VALUE <> @P , @RN:=@RN+1,@RN) RN ,
         @P:=L.VALUE P
FROM   (SELECT @RN:=0, @P:=0 ) RN,`LATENCY` L
#ORDER BY
) S
WHERE S.VALUE = 0

) S1 


JOIN 
(SELECT L.*,
         IF (L.VALUE <> @P1 , @RN1:=@RN1+1,@RN1) RN ,
         @P1:=L.VALUE P
FROM   (SELECT @RN1:=0, @P1:=0 ) RN,`LATENCY` L
#ORDER BY
)  T
ON S1.RN = T.RN-1 OR S1.RN = T.RN+1
```

The sub queries s and s1 identify blocks with value = 0 and the join simply picks adjacent row numbers.